# Autocomplete Textbox in vb.net using MySql

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, autocomplete

I am trying to make autocomplete function which starts suggesting from datatable when users types. It seems all right but it pops up Not Found. In my database all columns name and connections seems to be alright. I don't understand where is the problem as it's even not throws any errors.
[This is the link of files I uploaded on server](http://healthsaviour.com/default.aspx)

ASPX

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
    <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(function () {
            $("#area").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var param = { cityname: $('#area').val() };
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "Dafault.aspx/GetAreas",
                        data: JSON.stringify(param),
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    value: item
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2//minLength as 2, it means when ever user enter 2 character in TextBox the AutoComplete method will fire and get its source data. 
            });
        });

    </script>  

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <div class="form-items">
        Select Area<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="area" CssClass="area" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
```

VB

```
Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web.Services
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    <WebMethod>
    Public Shared Function GetAreas(areaname As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim area As New List(Of String)()
        Dim con As New MySqlConnection("Data Source=182.50.133.88;port=3306;Initial Catalog=db;User Id=user;password=pwd;")



        Dim query As String = String.Format("SELECT areaName FROM areas", areaname)
        'Note: you can configure Connection string in web.config also.
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        con.Open()
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            area.Add(reader.GetString(0))
        End While
        Return area
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: JavaScript is calling  url: "Dafault.aspx/GetCities", but the function is called GetAreas  ??

Comment: ...and you have it spelled `Dafault` instead of `Default` .

Comment: @MrGadget Thank you to inform such a silly mistake. I changed it but now it shows Internal Server Error in pop up.

Comment: @StupidRomeo I would be very careful and check what is in the `query` for your case. If you debug it, what does it generate? What SQL string?

Comment: @Ian It should generate list of areas from data tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WebMethod` expects `parameter` with same name which you have passed from `ajax`.

Change your `param` in `javascript` like this.

```
var param = { areaname : $('#area').val() };
```

Also you are using `asp:Textbox` which might change its id then it will not be found by jquery.

So you can use `ClientIDMode=static` so id of textbox will not be changed.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="area" CssClass="area" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Update**

Your query doesn't have a `where` clause so you are getting all records from database. Add a `where` clause and pass the areaname as `parameter` to query.

```
Dim query As String = String.Format("SELECT areaName FROM areas Where UPPER(areaName) like @areaName", areaname);
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@areaName",areaname.ToUpper()+"%");
```

**Update 2**

You can also check if the area name starts with the letter you have passed then add to list otherwise don't add in list.

```
if(reader.GetString(0).StartsWith(areaname))
area.Add(reader.GetString(0))
```

I don't know exact syntax of VB but i hope you will get the idea.

Comment: Thanks man. In this I'm getting the results but it pickup all letters which contains typed letter. e.g. If area name is kothrud & If I type k then only areas which starts from K should suggest. How do I do that

Comment: Your query doesn't have a `where` clause add a where clause.See the update in answer.

Comment: It shows Local variable cmd can not be referred to before it is declared.

Comment: Yes add after this line `Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)`

Comment: Nothing comes in output. See the link I made those changes http://healthsaviour.com/default.aspx

Comment: Because no data is returned i have checked the link. Can you debug the code to see what is happening ?

Comment: OK i got it you need to make comparison with exact case If you type capital K it will return data.

Comment: See the updated answer. I have converted matched with uppercase letters.

Comment: Case doesn't matter. If I type K or k in both the case results starts with k should show.

Comment: No. If I type K then only it returns values. I type k then nothing returns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105094/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-stupid-romeo).

Comment: Remove `string.Format` from query

`Dim query As String = "SELECT areaName FROM areas Where areaName like '" + areaname + "%'";`

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 1 letter that need to match with the suggestion, you can try this:

```
    While reader.Read()
        Dim str As String=reader.GetString(0)
        If str(0)= areaname then area.Add(str)
    End While
```